# Access property from outside a class in objective c

Tags: objective-c, object, interface, public

How can I set an property from outside an Objective C class?

I have a class called MyCtlr and in the MyCtrl.h I declared a variable called `status` like this:

```
@interface RejectController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UICustomLabel *lblMessage;
}

@property NSInteger status;

@end
```

Then I want to set it in another class to a specific value like this:

```
    MyCtrl *myCtrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyCtrlIdentify"];
    [myCtrl status:2]; //here triggers the error: No visible @interface for 'MyCtrl' declares the selector 'status:'

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myCtrl animated:YES];
```

but as soon as I try to set a value to status I get the error: `No visible @interface for 'MyCtrl' declares the selector 'status:'`

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a property, accessor methods are created for you. So you should either be doing:

```
[myCtrl setStatus:2];
```

or

```
myCtrl.status = 2;
```

Comment: cool, seems to work, but where does the setStatus function come from? I never declared it? and is there a difference between this two methods?

Comment: You need to read about properties and what they do for you (define memory storage and accessor methods to that storage, with access logic)

Comment: okay thanks! Would be great if you could provide me a link. Most stuff I found is very outdated.

Comment: probably not outdated, it hasn't changed, swift makes life a bit different but obj-c is explicit about the options